# Can I access values from where clauses in SQLite triggers?

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

I would like to trigger an update to a table based on the where clause of an insert to a different table. For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_key_table
BEFORE INSERT ON value_table
BEGIN
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO key_table (key_name) VALUES ('new_key_name');
END;
```

This would update key_table with the value 'new_key_name' when the following query is run:

```
INSERT INTO value_table (key_id, value) 
SELECT key_table.key_id, 'new_value' 
FROM key_table 
WHERE key_table.key_name = 'new_key_name';
```

However, I have not been able to find any way to get access to the 'new_key_name' value from the triggering query's WHERE clause.

I understand that I can just run the following two queries in sequence, it would just be inconvenient in this particular application:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO key_table (key_name) VALUES ('new_key_name');

INSERT INTO value_table (key_id, value) 
SELECT key_table.key_id, 'new_value' 
FROM key_table 
WHERE key_table.key_name = 'new_key_name';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An INSERT trigger can access only the values in the new record to be inserted.

You have to execute the two queries separately.

Alternatively, if you can modify all your applications, you could create a view with all three columns (`key_id`, `value`, and `key_name`), and create an INSTEAD OF trigger that executes both the 'real' INSERTs.